# Server side google oauth for php

Tags: php, server, drive

Trying to make an app and get my file from google drive but without auth window. something like curl or just a post token exchange.

Found that it was possible in older version, but cannot find any docs for new version.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, indeed that's possible!

Comment: How, could you please share the URL

Comment: @iehrich how? i found google services, think this might be a way...